# Upgrading to MySQL 5.7 on YUM

Tags: mysql, yum

I would really appreciate help. I'm new to Linux and Yum. I recently purchased a VPS and it only has MySQL 5.6. I want to update to 5.7 and I'm stuck. pulling hair out over here. I've gotten to the point where i enter command createrepo but there doesn't seem to be any directory created by it as i read there should be. The server is running CentOS 6.9. Here are the steps i followed:

1. Downloaded Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 / Oracle Linux 6 (Architecture Independent), RPM Package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/ .
2. Used FTP client to upload the file to my server in a directory called downloads.
3. in PuTTy went to the downloads folder and typed 'ls', i can see the file is there. it appears in red as "mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm"
4. typed createrepo /downloads while in the downloads directory and I get:

> Spawning worker 0 with 1 pkgs Workers Finished Gathering worker
> results
>
> Saving Primary metadata Saving file lists metadata Saving other
> metadata Generating sqlite DBs Sqlite DBs complete

ACCORDING to the documentation i read it's supposed to create another directory at this point but when i type ls there is still just the file there. when i run the command again as createrepo /downloads -v i get:

```
Spawning worker 0 with 1 pkgs
Worker 0: reading mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
Workers Finished
Gathering worker results

Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
Generating sqlite DBs
Starting other db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Ending other db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Starting filelists db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Ending filelists db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Starting primary db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Ending primary db creation: Wed Mar 21 06:30:38 2018
Sqlite DBs complete
```

I've also tried localinstall command on the file in the directory with "yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm and i get:

```
Loading "fastestmirror" plugin
Loading "security" plugin
Loading "universal-hooks" plugin
Config time: 0.033
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Local Package Process
rpmdb time: 0.000
Examining mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm: mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch
Excluding mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch
Nothing to do
```

I think the file may have been installed already kind of inadvertently as i have been struggling with this for hours but then when i call createrepo shouldn't it create the repository using the RPM file?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you use `yum` to install MySQL as documented at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Ok I will give that guide a try i tried several ones but did not see this one. I assume that Since I'm running CentOS 6.9 and this guide is for centOS 7 this guide is ok?

Comment: There should be a guide for CentOS 6.9 anywhere that does similar things

Comment: ok well on the page of this link you gave me there is no option for 6.9 so i just followed it as closesly as i could for 6.9. I went to the developer link to download the RPM for el6, downloaded it via wget command, verified with mdsum then ran command sudo rpm -ivh mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm and everything looks ok. But then i run "sudo yum install mysql-server" and it gets further than it did before and even lists some mysql filles i've never seen it list before but then ultimately says "No package mysql-server availabale; Nothing to do". What am i doing wrong? thanks again.

Comment: When I do "yum repolist" it also shows now "My SQL Connectors Community", "MySQL Tools Community", and "MySQL 5.7 Community Server" which wasnt there before i followed these steps.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to delete the file you created and use the steps below (Taken from a production box)

The repo uses the name `mysql-community-*` That's why you couldn't find the package `mysql-server` via `yum`

Create a new file `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo` and add the following;

```
[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/6/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

Then do;

```
yum clean all
yum upgrade mysql-community-server
```

Which should install & upgrade you to 5.7 - Remember to run `mysql_upgrade` after MySQL has restarted.

Comment: It doesn't work. I created a new question with my problems. Can you check this one, please? https://serverfault.com/questions/1155974/upgrade-mysql-5-6-to-8-not-working-on-aws-linux-based-ec2